# OKTA SSO SAML Response

Tags: java, single-sign-on, okta

Trying to setup a SSO for a Java web application built with Spring MVC.
I've registered my application to an OKTA server, got a Metadata URL and a SignOn URL. I'm using the SignOn URL from my application, authenticating with success, then a POST request is made with some form data that include a SAML Response object.

What should be the next step from here?
I've decoded the SAML response, and now from my understanding I need to get a token or a session ID that I'll need to use to my further requests to the OKTA server.

Edit 1:
Ran the [spring-boot-saml-example](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-spring-boot-saml-example), the authentication works as expected.
But, when trying to get the current session using [OKTA Session API](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/sessions.html#get-current-session) from the Spring application, an HTTP 404 code is returned. Fetching the current session using the browser work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [blog post](http://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/16/spring-boot-saml), this example uses Spring Security and an Okta SAML app .  Take a look at that, and if that doesn't help let us know.

Comment: I'm getting a `No IDP was configured, please update included metadata with at least one IDP` although the Metadata URL returns a 200 OK when called from browser.

Comment: In fact, the HTTP 403 returned from IDP is an issue from my side. Will fix and update.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [spring-webmvc-pac4j security library](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j) which provides SAML authentication for Spring MVC (Boot) app.

Configuration is straightfoward for Okta like for any other SAML identity provider: https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/demo-servlet.xml#L44 + https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/demo-servlet.xml#L214